# How to query in MongoDB array

Tags: mongodb

So, in my MongoDB I have several documents that look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a17b7f5f7ecf32c5ee0077"), 
    "MediaID" : "302048", 
    "MediaName" : "El Viejo y el Mar", 
    "MediaTypeID" : "384", 
    "MediaTypeName" : "Movie", 
    "Rating" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Description" : "La versión cinematográfica de la obra inmortal de Ernest Hemingway, sobre un viejo pescador cubano que logra atrapar un pescado gigantesco que lo arrastra lejos de la orilla.", 
    "MediaWebLink" : "", 
    "Duration" : "5160", 
    "FileID" : "523852", 
    "like_counter" : NumberInt(0), 
    "EntryId" : "", 
    "Tags" : [
        {
            "Key" : "Clasificacion", 
            "Value" : "B"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Genre", 
            "Value" : "Drama|Clásicas"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Pais", 
            "Value" : "Estados Unidos"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Directors", 
            "Value" : "John Sturges"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Actors", 
            "Value" : "Spencer Tracy"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Distribuidor", 
            "Value" : "Warner"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Subtitles", 
            "Value" : "Español"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Audio Version", 
            "Value" : "Inglés"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Sub-Genre", 
            "Value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Palabras Clave", 
            "Value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Prizes", 
            "Value" : ""
        }
    ], 
    "Metas" : [
        {
            "Key" : "Nombre original", 
            "Value" : "The Old Man And The Sea"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Synopsis corta", 
            "Value" : "Es la historia de un viejo pescador cubano que logra atrapar un pescado gigantesco que lo arrastra lejos de la orilla."
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Duracion", 
            "Value" : "01:26:00"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Ano", 
            "Value" : "1958"
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Score de titulo", 
            "Value" : "4"
        }
    ], 
    "AdvertisingParameters" : [

    ] 

}
```

Inside the document, there is an array called TAGS, where one Key=Distribuidor and the Value = Warner
What I need is to do a query where I could get all the distincts "distribuidor" values for all the documents that I have.

So far I have tried this:

```
db.catalogo.distinct( 'Tags.Value', { 'Tags.Key': 'Distribuidor' } )
```

But this is getting me all the values and not just for the "distribuidor" value.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline):

```
db.catalogo.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$Tags"
}, {
    $match: {
        "Tags.Key": "Distribuidor"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Tags.Value"
    }
})
```

Briefly, we have an [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), to expand your `Tags` array in multiple documents; then a [match](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), to filter out the Tags which don't have `"Distribuidor"` as `Key`, then a [group](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), that works as distinct of `Value` in this case (you can easily add a `count` for each Value, but that's not what you asked). The output would be something like

```
{ "_id" : "Warnero" }
{ "_id" : "Warner" }
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question, try this, UPD:

```
db.catalogo.find( {}, { 'Tags.Key': 1 } )
```

Comment: it did not work.    2016-01-22T14:38:38.770-0600 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: The first argument to the distinct command must be a string but was a object :
DBCollection.prototype.distinct@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1628:1
@(shell):1:1